# How attributes helps us to allow column interchange in a relational database?

Tags: database-theory, databases, relational-algebra

A relation on two sets $A$ and $B$ is defined as the subset of the cartesian product $$A\times B = \{(a,b),\ a \in A, b \in B\}$$

A database is also a relation and each entry is an ordered tuple respecting the cartesian product.

Now, interchanging the rows and the columns of a database does not change it. I can understand that a relation is just a set of tuples (called as row) so the order of elements in a set does not matter and hence row interchange will not pose a problem. But column interchange conflicts with the idea that a particular entry of the database is an ordered tuple.

So, attributes are used to tackle this problem. This is what I was told (verbatim):

Example table:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|}\hline
\text{Name}&\text{Roll No.}\\\hline
\text{Alex}&\text{2}\\\hline
\text{Fred}&5\\\hline
\text{Nate}&7\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

$\Rightarrow$ Fix a set $C$ also called the index set (here it can be $\{1,2\}$ or $\{\text{Name},\text{Roll No.}\}$)

$\Rightarrow$ Consider::$\{A_i|\ i\in C\}$, $A_i$ is the *type* of the attribute $i$ (here that is $A_1=\text{String}$ and $A_2=\text{Integer}$).

$\Rightarrow$  The cartesian product: $\prod_i A_i$ is seen as the collection of functions $$f : C \to \cup_i A_i$$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$

I was told that this definition of the cartesian product will allow us not to worry about the position of the column 'Name', etc. But I did not understand why. I would appreciate any kind of help and I apologize in advance for bad/incorrect formatting.

Comment: A function is a set, and therefore doesn't care about order. So, instead of modeling the table as $\{(Alex,2),(Fred,5),(Nate,7)\}$, it is being modeled as $\{\{(Name,Alex),(Rool No.,2)\},\{(Name,Fred),(Roll No.,5)\},\{(Name.Nate),(Roll No,, 7)\}\}$. The latter is a set of sets, each of which is a function (a set of pairs in which there is only one pair for each value of the first component).

Comment: Note that even though $\{(Name,Alex),(Roll No., 2)\}$ is a different object than $(Alex,2)$, still some call the first a tuple (row). It looks like in what you were told they are also reusing the name *Cartesian product* to have the new meaning of a set of these functions.

Comment: There are many variations of "relation" used in relational algebras/calculi/DBs. If headings are lists/ordered then changing tuple name order gives a new relation value. If headings are sets of attribute name-value pairs then changing attribute order in some experession denoting a heading doesn't give a different relation value. What is the exact definition of your kind of "relation"? And what exactly is "interchanging"--in a relation, or in an expression? And what exactly are your operators & expressions for denoting relations & operator calls?

Comment: That subscripting is very sloppy, suggest you write clearer statements with enough words to actually make sense instead of that pretend-math. And fully work through an example. Also calling that "Cartesian product" doesn't make it Cartesian product. It isn't Cartesian product. They should say they are defining a "relational (so-called) Cartesian product".

Comment: Even relational algebras/calculi that use ordered-tuple math relations typically abuse "Cartesian product" to mean something that isn't Cartesian product. The relational product they mean by it inputs an n-ary relation & a m-ary relation & outputs an (n+m)-ary relation, but Cartesian product inputs n sets & outputs a set of n-tuples.

Comment: @philipxy The flattening that occurs in the operation between relations, that is called Cartesian product, is also normally used in mathematics and people don't even stop to mention it. For example, when people write $(\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^3)\times\mathbb{R}^5=\mathbb{R}^2\times(\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^5)=\mathbb{R}^{10}$, the Cartesian products are being flattened in this way. They are not really equal.

Comment: @plop Agree, so much is (mercifully) trivially isomorphic and/or punned/abused when you are used to it. But confusing for beginners. I am reminded of Halmos re this sort of thing (coincidentally at the very point of generalized Cartesian product!), "There is no help for it, that is how mathematical language is in fact used nowadays [1960]".

Comment: @plop Thanks for the answer and the editing as well. So, each row is a function that maps column names/index to the respective values. And hence we do not need to worry about the order of the columns. The set of sets helped me to understand this.

Comment: @philipxy I apologize for the vague explanation. By relation, I meant a subset of cartesian products of n (the number of columns) sets. We can swap two columns in a database without affecting anything. That is the Roll No. column can come before the Name column. My semester has just started and it was my second class. So, I cannot answer about the operator part yet. I also thank you for the valuable feedback.

Comment: Your post & comment are unclear re tables vs pictures & user-visible vs implementation tables & whether a table includes a heading & just what the structure of the heading and/or body are & (hence) what "swapping"--an operation--is for any of those things. In your comment you say table values are subsets of Cartesian products. But since they have ordered tuples, changing column order does matter, so it seems tables are not just rows but include headings & that both are ordered--which you use as tables without order. Please just clearly define your terms. PS Clarifiy via edits, not comments.

Comment: PS Your class's relation-as-function means there's one empty relation and it contains no heading. That is different from having an empty relation for every heading. This means that your class must also introduce a notion of heading & heading-relation pairs if you ever want to say that a tabley thing has a heading even if it has no rows. Typically such presentations associate headings with variables. But they don't make it clear when what's really returned is a heading-body pair. There's lots of sloppiness like Cartesian products that aren't Cartesian products in relational model presentations.